# В каких случаях используется new FormData() при отправке данных с формы?

Tags: javascript

В каких случаях используется FormData ( const formData = new FormData();) при отправке данных с формы POST запросом. можно просто же отправить в body данные с формы.
когда надо записывать в объект formData, а когда нет? в чем различия?

Comment: Что значит «отправить в body данные с формы»?